# Verifying OAuth signature or request

Tags: java, servlets, oauth

I have to verify the request call from a server which is OAuth signed. This request call is made to my server, and i need to verify that request is made from that server. I have the oauth consumer key and consumer secret. I have been looking into signpost and jersey library APIs for signature  verification. They have not been of much help. 
The call is made from a particular server(with two-legged OAuth 1.0) to my servlet. Please suggest a simpler library or example to do the OAuth verification.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when coding a web service using the Play framework in Scala which I had to code using Java libraries in order to solve it so even though my code snippet is in Scala, I think that it can help. This answer may be coming a bit late but hopefully somebody might find it useful.

In my case, an external service is calling my REST endpoint while providing different oauth parameters inside the Authorization header. In order to validate the oauth_signature provided as part of these parameters, I had to extract the nonce and the timestamp parameter from the header and calculate a signature based on them plus based on a few other parameters including my oauth key and secret, and the original request uri.

This code is in scala but I think that you can infer what to do from it. It is also using the java OAuthSignatureCalculator so it may even be easier to code directly in Java.

```
private def getProtocolFromRequest[T](request: Request[T]): String = {
  // To handle the case where a SSL offloading is involved
  request.headers.get(HeaderNames.X_FORWARDED_PROTO) match {
    case Some(forwardedProto: String) => forwardedProto
    case _ => if(request.secure) "https" else "http"
  }
}

def isOAuthSignatureValid[T](request:  Request[T]): Boolean = {
  request.headers.get(com.ning.http.client.oauth.OAuthSignatureCalculator.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION) match {
    case Some(authorizationHeaders) =>
      val AuthRegex = ".*oauth_nonce=\"([^\"]*)\".*oauth_signature=\"([^\"]*)\".*oauth_timestamp=\"([^\"]*)\".*".r

      authorizationHeaders match {
        case AuthRegex(nonce: String, providedSignature: String, timestamp: String) =>
          val signatureCalculator = new OAuthSignatureCalculator(new com.ning.http.client.oauth.ConsumerKey(oauthKey, oauthSecret), new com.ning.http.client.oauth.RequestToken(null, ""))
          val params = request.queryString.map(query => new Param(query._1, query._2.head)).toSeq
          val protocol = getProtocolFromRequest(request)
          val url = s"$protocol://${request.host}${request.path}"

          val expectedSignature = signatureCalculator.calculateSignature(
            request.method,
            Uri.create(url),
            timestamp.toInt,
            nonce,
            new util.ArrayList(),
            scala.collection.JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(params)
          )
          expectedSignature.equals(URLDecoder.decode(providedSignature, "UTF-8"))
        case _ => false
      }
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

The flow is the following:

1. Grab the Authorization header
2. Create a OAuthSignatureCalculator by providing your oauth consumer key and secret. In my case I am not using any request token.
3. Extract the needed oauth parameters from the authorization headers: signature, nonce, timestamp
4. Use the OAuthSignatureCalculator to calculate a signature
5. Compare the provided signature with the calculated one. If they match, the caller is authentified, otherwise, it's not.

Hopefully that can help somebody